# How to get all the sum in aggregate function?

Tags: r, aggregate

Here's some sample data:

```
dat="x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
1   C  1 16 NA 16
2   A  1 16 16 NA
3   A  1 16 16 NA
4   A  4 64 64 NA
5   C  4 64 NA 64
6   A  1 16 16 NA
7   A  1 16 16 NA
8   A  1 16 16 NA
9   B  4 64 32 32
10  A  3 48 48 NA
11  B  4 64 32 32
12  B  3 48 32 16"

data<-read.table(text=dat,header=TRUE)   
aggregate(cbind(x2,x3,x4,x5)~x1, FUN=sum, data=data)   
 x1 x2  x3 x4 x5   
1  B 11 176 96 8
```

How do I get the sum of `A` and `C` *as well* in `x1`?

```
 aggregate(.~x1, FUN=sum, data=data, na.action = na.omit)  
   x1 x2  x3 x4 x5
 1  B 11 176 96 80
```

When I use `sqldf`:

```
library("sqldf")
sqldf("select sum(x2),sum(x3),sum(x4),sum(x5) from data group by x1")
  sum(x2) sum(x3) sum(x4) sum(x5)
1      12     192     192    <NA>
2      11     176      96      80
3       5      80      NA      80
```

Why do I get `<NA>` in the first line, but `NA` in the third line ?
What is the differences between them? Why do I get the `<NA>`? there is no `<NA>` in data!

```
str(data)
'data.frame':   12 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ x1: Factor w/ 3 levels "A","B","C": 3 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 2 1 ...
 $ x2: int  1 1 1 4 4 1 1 1 4 3 ...
 $ x3: int  16 16 16 64 64 16 16 16 64 48 ...
 $ x4: int  NA 16 16 64 NA 16 16 16 32 48 ...
 $ x5: int  16 NA NA NA 64 NA NA NA 32 NA ...
```

The sqldf problem remains here, why `sum(x4)` gets `NA`, on the contrary `sum(x5)` gets `<NA>`?

I can prove that all `NA` both in  x4 and  x5 is the same this way:

```
data[is.na(data)] <- 0     

> data
   x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
1   C  1 16  0 16
2   A  1 16 16  0
3   A  1 16 16  0
4   A  4 64 64  0
5   C  4 64  0 64
6   A  1 16 16  0
7   A  1 16 16  0
8   A  1 16 16  0
9   B  4 64 32 32
10  A  3 48 48  0
11  B  4 64 32 32
12  B  3 48 32 16
```

So the fact that sqldf treats `sum(x4)` and `sum(x5)` differently is so strange that I think there is a logical mess in sqldf. It can be reproduced in other pc. Please do first and then have the discussion go on.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8859124/na-values-using-sqldf

Comment: You get `<NA>` to distinguish a real `NA` value from the character representation of `NA`, e.g. `"NA"`. If you look at the return value from running that command, you get a `data.frame` in which the first three columns are of type `integer` and the fourth is of type `character`. I guess `sqldf` is converting the fourth to a factor somewhere along the way. Try `str( sqldf("select sum(x2),sum(x3),sum(x4),sum(x5) from data group by x1") )` to see what I mean.

Comment: SQLite assigns the column affinity according to the first row of the column and uses text if its NULL.  Some workarounds are: (1) use the same name for the output column as the input in which case sqldf will deduce that you wanted to coerce back to that type, (2) use `total` in place of `sum` in which case zero rows will total to 0 rather than NULL so the problem does not occur, (3) use sqldf's `method` arg to specify the classes, (4) use one of the other databases that sqldf supports (H2, MySQL, PostgreSQL) instead of SQLite. See `?sqldf` and http://sqldf.googlecode.com for more info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of how the formula method for `aggregate` handles `NA` values by default, you need to override that before using the `na.rm` argument from `sum`. You can do this by setting `na.action` to `NULL` or `na.pass`:

```
aggregate(cbind(x2,x3,x4,x5) ~ x1, FUN = sum, data = data, 
          na.rm = TRUE, na.action = NULL)
#   x1 x2  x3  x4 x5
# 1  A 12 192 192  0
# 2  B 11 176  96 80
# 3  C  5  80   0 80

aggregate(cbind(x2,x3,x4,x5) ~ x1, FUN = sum, data = data, 
          na.rm = TRUE, na.action = na.pass)
#   x1 x2  x3  x4 x5
# 1  A 12 192 192  0
# 2  B 11 176  96 80
# 3  C  5  80   0 80
```

---

Regarding `sqldf`, it seems like the columns are being cast to different types depending on whether **the item in the first row of the first grouping variable** is an `NA` or not. If it is an `NA`, that column gets cast as `character`.

Compare:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                 A = c(1, 1, NA, NA, NA),
                 B = c(NA, NA, 1, 1, 1))
sqldf("select sum(A), sum(B) from df1 group by id")
#   sum(A) sum(B)
# 1      2   <NA>
# 2     NA    3.0

df2 <- data.frame(id = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 1),
                  A = c(1, 1, NA, NA, NA),
                  B = c(NA, NA, 1, 1, 1))
sqldf("select sum(A), sum(B) from df2 group by id")
#   sum(A) sum(B)
# 1   <NA>      3
# 2    2.0     NA
```

However, there is an easy workaround: reassign the original name to the new columns being created. Perhaps that let's SQLite inherit some of the information from the previous database? (I don't really use SQL.)

Example (with the same "df2" created earlier):

```
sqldf("select sum(A) `A`, sum(B) `B` from df2 group by id")
#    A  B
# 1 NA  3
# 2  2 NA
```

You can easily use `paste` to create your `select` statement:

```
Aggs <- paste("sum(", names(data)[-1], ") `", 
              names(data)[-1], "`", sep = "", collapse = ", ")
sqldf(paste("select", Aggs, "from data group by x1"))
#   x2  x3  x4 x5
# 1 12 192 192 NA
# 2 11 176  96 80
# 3  5  80  NA 80
str(.Last.value)
# 'data.frame':  3 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ x2: int  12 11 5
#  $ x3: int  192 176 80
#  $ x4: int  192 96 NA
#  $ x5: int  NA 80 80
```

---

A similar approach can be taken if you want `NA` to be replaced with `0`:

```
Aggs <- paste("sum(ifnull(", names(data)[-1], ", 0)) `", 
              names(data)[-1], "`", sep = "", collapse = ", ")
sqldf(paste("select", Aggs, "from data group by x1"))
#   x2  x3  x4 x5
# 1 12 192 192  0
# 2 11 176  96 80
# 3  5  80   0 80
```

Comment: dear Ananda Mahto ,you still do not answer  why sqldf treat the NA differently.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature, I don't have an exact answer *why*, but I have a solution. I'm guessing this isn't as much a problem from the side of "sqldf", but more of something to do with SQLite. See [FAQ 14 at this page](https://code.google.com/p/sqldf/#14._How_does_one_read_files_where_numeric_NAs_are_represented_as) for a similar problem while reading data in. I'm presuming something similar is happening here.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the `data.table` way in case you're interested:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(data)
dt[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm=TRUE), by=x1]
#    x1 x2  x3  x4 x5
# 1:  C  5  80   0 80
# 2:  A 12 192 192  0
# 3:  B 11 176  96 80
```

If you want `sum` to return `NA` instead of the sum after removing NA's, just remove the `na.rm=TRUE` argument.

`.SD` here is an internal `data.table` variable that constructs, by default, all the columns not in `by` - here all except `x1`. You can check the contents of `.SD` by doing:

```
dt[, print(.SD), by=x1]
```

to get an idea of what's `.SD`. If you're interested check `?data.table` for other internal (and very useful) special variables like `.I`, `.N`, `.GRP` etc..

Answer (score 2):

`aggregate(data[, -1], by=list(data$x1), FUN=sum)`

I eliminated the first column because you don't use it in the sum, it is just a group variable to split the data (as a matter of fact I then used it in "by")

Comment: what is `data[,-1]` there?

Comment: I eliminated the first column because you don't have to consider it in the sum, it is just a group variable you have to use to split the data (as a matter of fact I used it in "by")

Comment: Maybe you could add this explanation in your answer to make it more complete and useful ;-)

Comment: You may also want, `na.rm=TRUE`? (depends on the OPs real data - in this example *all* values in a group are `NA` **or** all not `NA`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you would do this with the `reshape` package:

```
> # x1 = identifier variable, everything else = measured variables
> data_melted <- melt(data, id="x1", measured=c("x2", "x3", "x4", "x5"))
>
> # Thus we now have (measured variable and it's value) per x1 (id variable)
> head(data_melted)
  x1 variable value
1  C       x2     1
2  A       x2     1
3  A       x2     1
4  A       x2     4
5  C       x2     4
6  A       x2     1

> tail(data_melted)
   x1 variable value
43  A       x5    NA
44  A       x5    NA
45  B       x5    32
46  A       x5    NA
47  B       x5    32
48  B       x5    16

> # Now aggregate using sum, passing na.rm to it
> cast(data_melted, x1 ~ ..., sum, na.rm=TRUE)
  x1 x2  x3  x4 x5
1  A 12 192 192  0
2  B 11 176  96 80
3  C  5  80   0 80
```

Alternatively, you could have done `na.rm` during the `melt()`-ing process itself.

The great thing about learning `library(reshape)` is, quoting the author (["Reshaping Data with the
reshape
Package"](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v21/i12/paper)),

> "In R, there are a number of general functions that can aggregate data,
>   for example tapply, by and aggregate, and a function speciﬁcally for
>   reshaping data, reshape. Each of these functions tends to deal well
>   with one or two speciﬁc scenarios, and each requires slightly diﬀerent
>   input arguments. In practice, you need careful thought to piece
>   together the correct sequence of operations to get your data into the
>   form that you want. The reshape package grew out of my frustrations
>   with reshaping data for consulting clients, and overcomes these
>   problems with a general conceptual framework that uses just two
>   functions: melt and cast."